# Defining path directions on D*Lite

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, directed-graph, d-star

I'm currently working on an implementation of the D*Lite algorithm from Sven Koenig.
http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/papers/aaai02b.pdf. Basically I'm trying to understand all the details before starting to implement it. It seems that the algorithm works on directed graphs, that's the way to define the `Pred` and `Succ` functions.

How do I define the direction of the graphs and which the parameters decide the direction of the graphs. Should I use the value of some parameter like the `g` cost (which doesn't seem to be a good choice...since is the `g` cost along with the `rhs` value the one the algorithm updates) or the heuristic estimate of the distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D*, and D*-lite will both work on both directed and undirected graphs.

A graph is `G = (V, E)`, where `V` is a list of configurations (or states) that can be reached. `E` is a list of the connections between vertices. In a directed graph, `E` is a set of edges which are **ordered** pairs `(u, v)`, where both `u` and `v` are vertices. In an undirected graph, `E` is a set of **unordered** pairs.

Planning on an undirected graph is equivalent to planning on a directed graph, with a bidirectional edge. That is, if `(u,v)` is an edge `(v, u)` will also be an edge.

How you construct the graphs is application specific, and varies from simple grids to much more complex strategies like lattice approximations to forward kinematics.

Comment: Yes, ok, i have quite clear the difference from directed to undirected graph. But my question was more specific: how do I define the "direction" of the graph on D*Lite for the usual path planning (so 8 cell direction)? Do you mean that this decision is up to me and not "implied" in some way in the algorithm itself?                Second question: does D*Lite really work even on undirected graph, so Succ=Pred??                                                     Thank You

Comment: Yes you are correct, whether an edge exists is application specific. For example, on an eight connected grid, you will typically know where the center of each cell in the grid is. You can use vector math to calculate the distance from each cell to each of the `pred` or `succ` cells. Only allow edges that do not start or end in an obstacle. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, `succ` is allowed to be equivalent to `pred`, and does in many simple graphs (including eight connected grids)